# How to describe a situation that makes you nervous?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective to describe a situation that makes someone feel nervous.

"Nervous situation" - doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: What's wrong with _tense situation?_

Comment: Your ear is good. The situation isn't nervous, the person is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try "nerve-racking" if you mean really nervous!

(http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nerve%E2%80%93racking)